# move Animation between button on reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I am working on a project and I am new with animation and my objective is from a group of buttons when the user click on the button become active and a line will move from button to button.
I managed to make the button active and change color and etc, the only thing i still can`t make is that line to move from button to button.

This is my Reactjs code

```
 class AnimateButtonArea extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {  active: 0 };

  }


  setActive = (key) => {
    this.setState({ active: key });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className = "AnimateButtonArea">
        {data.AnimateButton.map((animateButton, key) => {
            return(
              <div key = {key} className = { this.state.active === key ? "AnimateButton active" : "AnimateButton"} >
                <Button type = {this.state.active === key ? "SofiaProBlackSmallActive" : "SofiaProBlackSmall"} onClick = {() => { this.setActive(key) }}  text = {animateButton.button} />
                <div className = "animatedLine" />
              </div>
            )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default AnimateButtonArea;
```

And this is my Sass code

```
.AnimateButtonArea
  display: inline-block
  
.AnimateButton
  display: inline-block
  margin-right: 147px  

.AnimateButton.active .animatedLine
  position: relative
  height: 8px
  left: 24px
  background: var(--yellow)
  border-radius: 40px
  text-align: center
  animation: grow 0.4s ease-out

@keyframes grow
  0%
    width: 0%

  100%
    width: 100%
```

UPDATE

Now I can move the line but now i want to increase the line and then decrease and move it

Here's the updated Reactjs part

```
  setActive = (key) => {
    this.setState({ active: key })
    
    var difference = key - this.state.active

    leftActive += 300 * difference

    style = { width: `calc(${leftActive}px + 120px)`}

    setTimeout(()=> this.beActive(leftActive), 1000)
  }

  beActive = (leftActive) => {
    style = { marginLeft: `calc(${leftActive}px)`, with: `120px`}
    console.log(style);
  }
```

Comment: Could you attach image of your work and write down what you want to move please?

Answer (score 0):

To move between positions, the line should be an unique object outside of the mapped array. Then you can manipulate the positioning (with margin, transform or left) based on the key/(array.length-1) with inline styles.

Set css transition: all 1s ease; to animate.

Comment: well i used your idea and now it works. Now i have a problem where instead just moving i von him to increase his width and then decrease and move to the button and i will update my question to put the code

Comment: You can pass (e) => this.setActive(key, e) to the function and use e.target.offsetWidth to set a width state.

Comment: ok I will use that but how I am going to help resolving the increase and decrease and then move of the line? @maggiathor

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the width to state (this.state.activeWidth) and include it in the line style object. {width:this.state.activeWidth}

Comment: I already have did that but the problem now is I want the line first increase width and when its increased the line will decrease his width and move with left position

Comment: You have a typo in the style object => with ,maybe it's that?

Comment: I corrected that "with" to "width"but the problem is the same, is there an event or something that makes the style the line and then style again? @maggiathor

Comment: Probably because you are not triggering a rerender since no state is changed in your beActive function, but that is a guess.